# $H$ is a group acting on a set $K$, $\phi: H \rightarrow Sym(K)$ is homomorphism. Prove that $ker(\phi)=\cap_{x\in K} G_{x}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

$H$ is a group acting on a set $K$, $\phi: H \rightarrow Sym(K)$ is homomorphism. Prove that $ker(\phi)=\cap_{x\in K} G_{x}$

I have no idea how to prove this, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: $ker(\phi)$ is the set of elements of $h\in H$ which act as the identity, in other words the set of all $h \in H$ which fix (stabilize) every $x \in K$.

Comment: Maybe this is clear from the context, but I think you should not forget to mention that $\phi$ is the homomorphism associated with the action of $H$ on $K$ and not an arbitrary one.

Comment: What does $Sym(K)$ mean?

Comment: It is symmetric group, which is all permutations of  K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $h \in \text{ker }\phi$.Then $h$ induces the identity permutation on all of $K$, that is: $h\cdot k = k$, for all $k \in K$. Hence $h \in H_k$ (the stabilizer under $H$ of the element $k$) for each $k$, so $h \in \bigcap\limits_{k \in K} H_k$.

On the other hand, if $h$ is in the intersection, $h$ stabilizes every $k$, so the permutation of $K$ which $h$ induces is: $k \mapsto k$ for all $k \in K$, that is, the identity permutation, so $h \in \text{ker }\phi$.